# Responsive slider for Ecommerce Application

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, slider

Hi I'm looking for a responsive Jquery minimalist slider that shows thumbnails on hover.  Can someone please recommend such a slider?  I need to use this slider for a responsive Ecommerce Application.  Any help would be much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check [the url](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-For-Image-Zoom-On-Hover-picZoomer/) it might help you. Its not perfect solution. You will need to do some changes in it.

Comment: Downvoter, please mention reason as well.